# Translate pipe with html tags

Tags: html, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, translate

In Angular while using `translate` pipe I provide `string` to it to get the result message for my validation service. And it worked fine for me until I needed message with underline text. And I thought it'd be nice to work with html instead of simple text. So how can I do it without changing any css or adding logic ?

```
<div class="field-error text-small"
     *ngIf="showMessage">
  {{ errorMessage | translate }}
</div>
```

The string I need to provide: `"The e-mail or password is incorrect. <u>Have you forgotten your password?</u>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically we just have to replace interpolation with property binding. We can bind to `innerHtml` and it will solve our problem. Offical docs: [github.com/ngx-translate/core#6-use-html-tags](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#6-use-html-tags)

```
<div class="field-error text-small"
     *ngIf="showMessage" 
     [innerHtml]="errorMessage | translate">
</div>
```

Comment: Just attaching the official doc link where the same thing is mentioned :

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#6-use-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Following should also work:

```
<div class="field-error text-small"
     *ngIf="showMessage" 
     translate>errorMessage
</div>
```